# Active_scaffold add to list associated table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :phone, :address, :city, :state, :zip,
                  :notes, :is_admin, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  has_many :consumers
 end

class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

In consumers_controller I am trying to include some field from **agency**

```
 active_scaffold :consumer do |conf|
    list.columns = [
      :agency, :event
    ]
 end
```

There are such associations Agency -> Event -> Consumer. And there is no association between agency and consumer, only through event.

but it causes an error.

How Can I include to list a any field form agency table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was a quite simple but most likely inefficient.

I have added a method to Consumer model:

```
class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def agency_name
    self.event.agency[:name]
  end
end
```

Then I have added a virtual column to list:

```
list.columns = [
  :agency_name, :event, ... ]
```

That's all.

Comment: How to implement search on event.agency.name ??

Comment: @aashish, what did you mean? How to add active_scaffold search field on event.agency.name? Or just build ActiveRecord query?

Comment: if you meant the first one so the probable decision via API columns is 
`class ConsumersController < ActionController::Base
  active_scaffold :consumers do |config|
    config.columns[:agency_name].search_sql = 'event.agency.name'
    config.search.columns << :agency_name
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Getting-Started), I think what you want is this:

```
active_scaffold :consumer do |conf|
  conf.columns = [:agency, :event]
end
```

Also, make sure a consumer has an agency association or column.

Comment: Problem is **consumer** has an association with **agency** only through **event** table.